# How to use Angular google maps with map-icon

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I recently started an angular project where I need to display a lot of differents things on the map.

I initially started with agm( https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps ), but I just found out about map-icon( https://github.com/scottdejonge/map-icons ), which seems awesome, because all the icons that I need are in this pack and I will also need to have several colors and form.

Is there a way to associate the both together? Right now I can't figure out how, because in agm, you have to provide an URL, and map-icon seems to work with html/css?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on a 3rd party libraries/modules to implement the map, it would be a lot easier and better if you just load the script directly so that you can use google map's official documentations on [marker icons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple). To do this, simply load the JS map script in the index.html.

Here is a working sample for your reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-map-custom-icons-64402069

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
<my-app>loading</my-app>
```

**style.css**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.map {
  height:100%;
}
```

**map-with-marker.component.html**

```
<div #map class="map"></div>
```

**map-with-marker.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
declare const google: any;

@Component({
  selector: "my-maps",
  templateUrl: "./map-with-marker.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./map-with-marker.component.css"]
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("map", { static: true }) mapElement: any;
  map: any;
  image =
    "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png";
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    var center = { lat: -33.8569, lng: 151.2152 };
    const mapProperties = {
      center: center,
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(
      this.mapElement.nativeElement,
      mapProperties
    );
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: center,
      map: this.map,
      icon: this.image
    });

    //adding markers by click
    this.map.addListener("click", e => {
      //Determine the location where the user has clicked.
      this.addMarker(e.latLng);
    });
  }
  addMarker(latLng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: this.map,
      icon: this.image
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing this, the only issue that I've: The marker collection is coming from an observable collection(that will change), and I'm not sure how to synchronize this. How would you do this?
Also, I'm not a big fan of creating HTML elements in the typescript file, its brings a lot of others issues(like: who is gonna unsubscribe this click event listener?)